How do you add aliases for the dlv debugger?
When I use Go's command line debugger, dlv, I start by running the Go code from dlv like so:
$ dlv debug simple.go

Now, I cannot simply hit "n" to run the first line of your program. If I issue "n", the program will run to completion.
The Go way is to create a breakpoint in the main program of the main package, represented to dlv as main.main. So the first command from within the debugger is:
(dlv) break main.main
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x49ceee for main.main() ./simple.go:7

I don't want to type that every time. Sheesh, that's like 100 characters of typing. I want to create an alias (or a command that gets executed before I get to enter my first command).
Start the dlv session, create an alias call 'main', verify that it was accepted:
$ dlv debug simple.go
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) config alias "break main.main" main
(dlv) config -list
aliases                   map[break main.main:[main]]
substitute-path           []

Try to use the "main" alias:
(dlv) main
Command failed: command not available

I tried other unique alias names instead of "main", just to verify that "main" wasn't the offender.
